# How to capture player moment with webcam and use that as an input in a game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing, pygame

I want to make a boxing game and move the player with the help of capturing moment of the player by using image processing. I have tried capturing moment in python using OpenCV but how could i use that input in a game environment ?
and which tool i should use for that ??
This is my first question here please cooperate.
Thanks

Comment: your pose detection SW should inject window messages into the game itself inserting key strokes into its `WndProc`. Similar To Kinect Keyboard project. Another option is to create driver for virtual Joystick and drive such instead of injecting directly into the game. Both approaches are out of my field of expertise but at least you have something to google. I would chose the first one as it is a magnitudes simpler and already done by others so may be you will find also some sources online. Also see [Connecting a Motion Simulator to GTA](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6770/4709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just buy a kinect and use Microsoft's SDK.  It has skeleton tracking built into it.

As far as game input, you can build standard serial stuff in unity3d in its background scripts.  Either implement the camera directly into unity or else create a serial forwarder that runs on the computer, which reads the camera data, processes it, and then streams computed information to unity.